# Insert data from text file to csv column

Tags: python, csv

Sorry I can't seem to find the right term for the title. Basically, what I want to do is to insert the data from the text file into the CSV's C column. Inserting the whole line 2 from text into c1 cell of the csv, line 3 to c2 and so on. No need to use D column as I will be converting the results from the C column back to a text file (waypoint) once I applied a conditional statement to delete some line depending on the level (column B).

To give you an idea, what I am doing is a waypoint generator/editor for a drone's mission planner.

[image]

Comment: Please supply a **[mcve]**. No images or links, please.

Comment: Is that your data from a text file? Can you substitute the spaces by commas? Maybe you should consider to use Pandas to convert your data into dataframes and you'll be able to handle with it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If I have a waypoint file "waypoints.wp':

```
QGC WPL 110
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

And a csv file 'data1.csv':

```
\Test01.jp,Level 3
\Test02.jp,Level 3
\Test03.jp,level 1
```

Then I can join them as you requested with:

```
waypoints = []
with open('wp.waypoints', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        waypoints.append(line)

with open('data1.csv', 'r') as infile, open('data1_out.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    n=1
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.strip() +","+waypoints[n])
        n+=1
```

This produces a file 'data1_out.csv':

```
\Test01.jp,Level 3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
\Test02.jp,Level 3,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
\Test03.jp,level 1,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

BTW, it would be great if you would provide data files in your questions so we don't have to try to devise them in order to answer your question. You will get more answers by providing data we can work with...